# C++ memoization not appending map object

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to practice basic dynamic programming in C++, but for some reason, it isn't inserting new values into the `std::map` object. As a result, it just runs like a standard fibonacci function instead of the fast version made with dynamic programming. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
int fib(int n, std::map<int, int> memo = {}) {
    if (memo.count(n) >= 1) {
        return memo[n];
    }
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(n,result));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `memo` should be passed by reference. Also, your first `if` unnecessarily searches the map twice, you should be using `find`.

Comment: Pass memo by reference, and it will work.

Comment: This must be a dupe.... has been asked so many times...

Comment: Also: one must note that using a `std::map` for the Fibonacci sequence is VERY inefficient...

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a new `map` each time, as you're passing `memo` by value, not by reference.

An alternative way to implement this is to create the `map` once, and then pass it by reference to the actual implementation. The example below does this, and has the advantage that it hides how you do the memoization:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    std::map<int, int> memo;
    return fib_impl(n, memo)
}

int fib_impl(int n, std::map<int, int> &memo) {
    if (memo.count(n) >= 1) {
        return memo[n];
    }
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(n,result));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing memo as value type making things slower. You can pass memo as reference type like below:

```
int fib(int n, std::map<int, int> &memo) {
    if (memo.count(n) >= 1) {
        return memo[n];
    }
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(n,result));
        return result;
    }
}
int main(){
    map<int,int>memo;
    cout<<fib(5,memo)<<"\n";
}
```

Or, you can global declaration of memo.

```
map<int,int>memo; 
int fib(int n) {
    if(memo.count(n)>=1)return memo[n];
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(n,result));
        return result;
    }
}

int main(){
     
     cout<<fib(10)<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. However, although your final solution is correct, it has nothing to do with being lower... passing `memo` by value will never work. See the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say you're passing memo by value, this way it doesn't keep values and reuse values. Because passing by value prevents memo from being modified, as only copy is modified and then lost.

You have to pass it by reference. But passing by reference is a bit tricky, because you have to create memo outside of a function and pass it to function manually. Other answers give examples how to pass it from outside by reference.

I want to show you other ways of doing this.

First variant is to create and pass down a [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). This method allows users of your function not to care about creating memo themselves, they don't need to pass anything. More than that this memo function argument may become now an optional argument and can be created automatically by function call. Lets see how it looks like:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/cG3daPe8Y)

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int fib(int n, std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> memo =
        std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>>()) {
    if (memo->count(n))
        return memo->at(n);
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
        memo->insert(std::pair<int, int>(n, result));
        return result;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fib(45) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1134903170
```

which is correct output for Fibonacci of 45, as we can see in [Wolfram Alpha page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci%2845%29).

One can see that in method above I don't have to pass anything to fibonacci function, optional argument with shared pointer is created automatically.

One may be tempted to pass optional argument as mutable reference, like so:

```cpp
int fib(int n, std::map<int, int> & memo = std::map<int, int>()) {
    ..........
    fib(n - 1, memo) + ...
}
```

this kind of syntax above would be very handy and would solve the problem, but unfortunately C++ doesn't provide ability to assign temporary object to mutable reference. So above code doesn't work and doesn't compile.

One can only assign temporary object to `const &`, like below:

`std::map<int, int> const & memo = std::map<int, int>()`

but const reference will not allow us to modify underlying memo and change its values.

So shared pointer used above saves us in this case by allowing to create temporary object and allowing to modify it and pass down recursively.

One more interesting way of solving your task is using `thread_local` variable inside function's body:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/sr9qsdrPr)

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int fib(int n) {
    thread_local std::map<int, int> memo;
    if (memo.count(n))
        return memo.at(n);
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int, int>(n, result));
        return result;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fib(45) << std::endl;
}
```

solution above allows us not to pass anything at all to function, but instead keep memo as local function's variable.

Thread local modifier allows us to reuse same computed values inside memo for each thread. This thread_local modifier is handy in case if you intend to use function from multiple cores and/or threads. This modifier allows not to use any mutexes to synchronize writes to it. But memo values would be shared only within each thread separately. Next solution saves us from this by sharing value between all threads using `static` modifier.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/GW4fqxaqs)

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int fib(int n) {
    static std::map<int, int> memo;
    if (memo.count(n))
        return memo.at(n);
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int, int>(n, result));
        return result;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fib(45) << std::endl;
}
```

`static` method above same as thread local method allows not to pass anything to function. Also it allows to share all memo values globally, between different calls and between different threads/cores. But unlike thread local solution static method is not thread safe, meaning you can't use it without mutex-synchronization, so actually correct way of using static variable is following:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/jPfzqPTWa)

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int fib(int n) {
    static std::recursive_mutex mux;
    static std::map<int, int> memo;
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mux);
    
    if (memo.count(n))
        return memo.at(n);
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else {
        int result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        memo.insert(std::pair<int, int>(n, result));
        return result;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fib(45) << std::endl;
}
```

one can see above that I used recursive mutex, which is correct way of synchronizing recursive function. Now with this mutex our function is thread safe, meaning that we can use it on multi core threads.